# Install ZOPE2 without buildout

Tags: plone, zope, buildout

In pre-buildout-times one would install ZOPE2 by downloading the tarball of http://old.zope.org/Products/Zope/ and do the configure/make/install-procedure.
Since ZOPE version 2.12 releases are made on pypi. Would it still be possible to install newer ZOPE2-versions the same way manually without using buildout?

Perspectively Plone is ment to be put on top ZOPE2, but to narrow down the question for now,  an answer only concerning ZOPE2 is very welcome.

Comment: BTW here is a interesing post from 2008 writen by Tres Seaver, one of the ZOPE-pioneers, musing on pros and cons of buildout: https://palladion.com/home/tseaver/obzervationz/2008/bulidout_vs_plain_setuptools

Answer (score 2):

I may be late to the party but:

As a starting point: There is the projects installation docs at https://zope.readthedocs.io/en/2.13/INSTALL-virtualenv.html which worked fine (and is without buildout) the last time I tried.

Since I use virtualenv and pip a lot, the above method becomes cumbersome fast (installation from different path than pypi and local equivalent, accidentally upgrading wrong packages when installing more packages) I made an almost pure reference installation and then just did a `pip freeze > zope_2.13_requirements.txt`.

Now I can just create a new virtualenv and do a quick `pip install -r zope_2.13_requirements.txt`, can do it directly via pipy and have a fresh installation whenever I need.

Comment: Yes right, that's another possibility. I was looking for the "drop files in dir and done"-approach, but good you mentioned it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main part of the question probably is that you probably want to use Zope 3 and not legacy Zope 2 (which e.g. Plone still depends on). Zope is not a signle, coherent, entity. What components of Zope stack you want to use (zope.interface, zope.component, ZODB, Medusa web server, Zope management interface, others?) All are individual Python packages and can be used as is in any Python application with normal Python package workflow.

Buildout is nothing but scripts, templates and Python package installer with advanced dependency solving.

You can still install all Zope packages by hand, resulting a lenghty `requirements.txt`. Zope 2 comes with command line scripts for creating and maintaining databases and you can call these scripts by hand, no need to go through buildout. You can also create configuration files by hand, e.g. looking the examples generated by buildout if you have some specific legacy project in mind.

For example, [substanced](http://www.substanced.net/), a CMS based on Pyramid and ZODB, does not rely on buildout. Pyramid internally uses `zope.interface`, `zope.component` and various other packakages.

Comment: The requirement is to use Plone-4 with ZODB. Would it still be about downloading and do the above procedere? Substance D. looks neat, got to give it a shot one day.

Comment: @fmue: Plock is an alternative install method for Plone: https://github.com/plock/plock - However as the authors state on Github page, it uses buildout internally as other tools don't just cope with the complexity.

Comment: Ok thank you, plock seems interesting also. So, the "old-style" where one could simply dump modules into the products-directory is not possible anymore? If you'd had an how-to example on the suggested way with installing manually and extending the requires.txt, that'll be very helpful.

Comment: @fmue: Smart people have tried it. They gave up. So I suggest stick with what everybody else is doing.

Comment: Sorry, but to do something *only because* everyone else is doing it, is not an argument. I don't get, if Plone is the problem or already simply installing ZOPE2 is not easily possible. Your answer implies it's doable, but no concrete example :-(

Comment: @fmue: Because it is too cumbersome to do it with the modern stack - that's why there are no examples available. It is easier with buildout. Plone has 300+ package dependencies. Managing them yourself instead of relying on Plone core team work with buildout is shitloads of work. So if you are totally crazy and want to undertake this work you can do it. Also you can design a spaceship to fly you to Mars. But think if it is worth of it.

Comment: Are you able to describe how to install ZOPE2 without buildout, the "old-school-way", where one can dump pckgs into the directory and that's it, or not? Also interesting would be to see the attempts of the smart people, if you have any pointers, thanks.

Comment: You cannot dump (most of) packages to a folder in anymore as modern systems use standard way of installing packages. Dumping packages to a folder was not without its problems. E.g. you could not define the order of  which different packages were applied.

Comment: Here is official Python packaging and installation guide https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: If you want find earlier attempts please feel free to explore Plone conference material - you might find something in lighting talks and such.

Comment: Times change: https://www.fourdigits.nl/blog/installing-plone-5-using-pip/

Comment: @Petri What is this heresy